# Approximate area of circle/triangle intersection based on vertex-center distances

Tags: geometry

Given a circle and a triangle (all coordinates known), I'd like to approximate the area of the intersection $S$ (or actually the fraction of the triangle that is inside the circle). All coordinates are known, so I could do an exact calculation. However, I'd rather do a quick approximate calculation, possibly based on the distances $d_i$ between the triangle vertices $t_i$ and the circle center $c$ and the triangle's area (since I have these available already).

Additional assumptions:

1. Either $\forall i: x(t_i) \ge 0$
2. or $\forall i: x(t_i) \ge 0 \& y(t_i) \ge 0 $

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with so far is based on the mean: With assumption 2 chosen, $r/mean(d_i)/2$ gives this for 1000 random triangles (with $0\le  x,y\le 2r$):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is always assumed that the center of the coordinate system is the center of the circle.

In my opinion, the question can be conisdered in different cases:

**Case 1:** All the points are outside the circle. No intersection so the S = 0.

**Case 2:** All the points are inside. Since you have the coordinates, you can measure the sides of triangles. Then it is possible to use Heron's formula to measure the area S.

For example, if we call the side that connects $d_1(x_1,y_1)$ to $d_2(x_2,y_2)$ as $L_{12}$ then this side can be measured by: $L_{12}= \sqrt {(y_2-y_1)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}$ then by using the heron's formula the area S can be measured. $$Heron's\,Formula: S=\sqrt {s(s-L_{12})(s-L_{13})(s-L_{23})},\quad s = \frac{L_{12}+L_{13}+L_{23}}{2}$$

**Case 3:** One end point is inside, for example $d_1$, and the other two are outside.

You can use the equation of the lines $L_{12}$ and $L_{13}$ and find their intersections with the circle.

The equation of the line $L_{12}$: $y-y_1=(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})(x-x_1)$

Circle equation: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (always assuming that the origin of the coordinate system is the center of the circle.)

Finding the intersection: $x^2+((\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})(x-x_1)+y_1)^2=r^2$ and you find the x. Then you replace the x to find the y.

Up to now you have find the intersection between $L_{12}$ and the circle. In the same way you can find the intersection between $L_{13}$ and the circle.

Let call these two points as $C_1(x_{L_{12}},y_{L_{12}})$ and $C_2(x_{L_{13}},y_{L_{13}})$. These two points helping you to find the area of S.

[image]

The area of S1 can be measured by using Heron's formula knowing the sides a, b, c as shown in the figure. Having the coordinates let you to have the sides.

To find out the S2, it is necessary to find the angle $\theta$. By having the coordinates $C_1(x_{L_{12}},y_{L_{12}})$ and $C_2(x_{L_{13}},y_{L_{13}})$ this angle can be measured easily in radians. $$\theta = arctan(\frac{y_{L_{12}}}{x_{L_{12}}})-arctan(\frac{y_{L_{13}}}{x_{L_{13}}})$$

Therefore the S2 would be equal to:

$$S2=[Section\;of\;the\;circle\;confine\;by\;\theta]-[Isosceles\;triangle\;area] =\frac{\theta}{2\pi}(\pi r^2) - \frac{1}{2}c\sqrt{r^2-\frac{c^2}{4}}$$

Then the area $S=S1+S2$.

**Case 4:** One end point is outside, for example $d_3$, and the other two are inside.

This case will be very similar to case 3.

---

Having the coordinates also let you to write $x_i$ and $y_i$ as the function of $d_i$.

For example for $d_1(x_1,y_1)$,

$$x_1 = d_1cos(\theta_1),y_1 = d_1sin(\theta_1),\theta_1 = arctan(\frac{y_1}{x_1})$$

Therefore, all the previous calculations can be done as function of $d_i$.